# How can I determine the unit vectors in elliptic coordinate system and then prove that they're orthogonal?

Tags: coordinate-systems

How can I calculate the unit vector in elliptic coordinate system? I don't know any trasnformation from cartesian coordinate to elliptic one. 
And then how do we prove that they're in fact orthogonal?

Comment: It might be helpful if you tell us what formulas you *do* know, to begin with.